# how to make a loop only counts up and never counts down until it breaks

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

i'm making a trailing stop that trails the (high) by a distance of (risk)
that goes like this

```
PTB= ta.valuewhen(golong,high,0)
pvtl= ta.valuewhen(golong,ta.lowest(2),0)

if (golong) and strategy.position_size ==0 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=PTB+0.01, limit=PTB+0.01)
    entry_p := PTB+0.01
    low_p   :=  pvtl-0.01
    risk := entry_p-low_p
exit = pvtl-0.01
for y = 1 to 10
    if high > entry_p + risk*y
        exit := entry_p + risk*(y-1)
    if strategy.position_size ==0 
        break
strategy.exit("Long", stop=exit)
```

it works just fine, except for one problem .. if the high crosses a threshold, the exit will update as intended and the stoploss will move up to the next step ,  but the problem is : if the next candle's high was lower than that threshold, the exit will update once more and lower the stoploss. which is a problem for me.. I want it once it moved forward, to never go back until the loop breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for`-loop is called on each bar. The `high > entry_p + risk * y` condition can be true on several bars in a row, and it is not tied to the value of the `exit` variable, so its value can be reassigned several times in a row regardless of how high `exit` is. Hard ot say without full code, but something like `exit := math.max(exit, entry_p + risk*(y-1))` might work: you'll check that the new exit value is higher than the previous one before changing it.

That being said, `strategy.exit()` already has a built-in trailing stop, so this all might be excessive. Use `trail_price` or `trail_points` to specify the level at which the stop is activated (`trail_points=0` will activate the stop instantly) and once activated, the stop will trail below X ticks the price (where X is specified via the `trail_offset` parameter).

Comment: actually this is the full code, the rest of the code are some other stuff that has nothing to do with entry and exit .. sadly the `exit := math.max(exit, entry_p + risk*(y-1))` didn't work. also I'm aware of the built in trail points and trail price, I've tried them before but couldn't make it work.